# How to join multiplte node.js intances to single domain?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js

I have on the same IP several node.js instances. Each instance running on a different domain via **nginx** reverse proxy.

For instance:

```
map_hash_bucket_size 128;

map $host $backend_servers {
  hostnames;
  default       127.0.0.1:3000;

  example.com   127.0.0.1:3001;
  example.net   127.0.0.1:3002;
  example.org   127.0.0.1:3003;
}

server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://$backend_servers; # upstream here
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I want to direct all the traffic from `example.com` with path prefix `/foo` to `127.0.0.1:3002` and remove `example.net` from the server.

Old links to `example.net/bar` should be redirect with status **301 Moved Permanently** to `example.com/foo/bar`.

This is my final goal:

```
example.com      >> 127.0.0.1:3001
example.com/foo  >> 127.0.0.1:3002
example.net      >> example.com/foo  # 301 redirect
example.org      >> 127.0.0.1:3003   # no change
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show any efforts to do it

Comment: I add my current configuration. I need a hint how to continue.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify nginx proxy server configuration like this:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
                }
    location /foo {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
    }
} 
server {
    server_name example.org;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003;
    }
}
server {
    server_name example.net;
    listen 80;
    return 301 http://example.com/foo;
}
```

Comment: I try it. It's look like the first server ignore the second location section and use only the first one. Switching order doesn't help.

Comment: Try change  `location /foo {...}` to `location ~* /foo/ {...}`

Comment: Hmm, Does nginx configtest are ok?

Comment: Just check it more deeply with the docs here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location it's seems that's works fine. my bad. The problem is that it send to port 3002 the full path "/foo/bar" instead of "/bar". I added `rewrite /foo(/.+|/?) $1 break;` and it's works!

Comment: Add to `location ~* /foo/` section:  `rewrite   ^/foo/(.*)$  /$1  permanent;`

Comment: Congradulations